# How to define a sort key for spectrum tables

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a use case where I join a redshift table with a large spectrum table. I see it's mentioned in best practices that choosing the sort key in join condition will aid the join operation. How do one specify sort key for an external table like spectrum.

Any help that points to understanding a query execution plan or help deconstruct a complex query to understand it's inefficiencies will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort key concept only applies to normal tables stored in Redshift itself. For external tables you can define partitions to minimize the amount of data accessed by Redshift Spectrum.

- [Improving Amazon Redshift Spectrum query performance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-performance.html)
- [Twelve Best Practices for Amazon Redshift Spectrum](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/)

Comment: Thanks for the links. It addresses few of the looming questions I had